# Can I Make My Chrome Extension Icon Respond to Links Being Dropped On It?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like users to be able to drag and drop links onto my extension icon next to the omnibox and have my extension read in the link. Is there an API to do this?

Comment: It shoulds like an interesting idea though. You should file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such an API does not exist.

If you want to have a drop target, then I suggest to insert custom HTML in the current page in response to a [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) event using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).